# Firebase Realtime Database Advanced Security Rules

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

right now I'm working on a project where I need to dive deeper into Firebase security rules but I am not the biggest expert in this topic and I also haven't found a solution for what I need to have online.

I have a user system in the Realtime Database which has the following structure:

users -> username -> myProfile / friends / and more...

In Cloud Firestore I have stored the username so that if someone logs in he can get his username out of the document in Cloud Firestore and read the document with the title of his username in the Realtime Database (I hope that makes sense).

Now I want to write security rules which allow the user to only read his own document (which does not have the title of his uid but of his username)...
Also, I want to allow other users to read the data in users -> username -> myProfile, but only if the username of the requesting user is contained in users -> username -> friends of the person, who is requested.

**To clarify an example:**

Person A logs into his account, he gets his username from Cloud Firestore and wants to access his document in the Realtime Database named by his username.
Then he wants to read the data of Person B in the RD, but he should only be allowed to do this if his username is saved into the array in the friends array in the profile of Person B.
Everybody must be able to read the friends array from everyone, but only able to read the myProfile data, if his username is contained in the friend array of the other person.

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL32O.png)

I would be super thankful for any help! If something is unclear just ask!

Micha

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your db structure? It'll be easier to understand.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've added that, I hope you can see how it works, every user has the same structure like this. I hope its understandable:)